# Strong Coupling between DAOClasses, getting references result in StackOverflow

Tags: java, database, stack-overflow, dao, decoupling

I've been dealing with DAOClasses and I've come accross a serious problem which forces me to reorganize my entire project. However I have no clue on how to solve this problem.

Suppose I have 3 Entities:

```java
public class User {

    private int id;
    private int cfu;
    private String name;
    private String surname;

}

public class Project {

    private int ID;
    private String info;
    private Doc doc;

}

public class Doc {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private ArrayList<Project> projects;

}
```

Each of this classes has its own DAO and its own table (regarding `Doc` the table does not keep reference of `Projects` IDs);

Among their various methods, DAOClasses uses these 2 methods:

- `read` allows to create a element of type T given the ID
- `readAll` allows to recover all elements of type T given a filter

When I call `read`method for `DocDAO` it is necessary to verify whether `Project` table contains Doc elements, if so create those elements thanks to `ProjectDAO` `readAll` and add them to its ArrayList. But also `ProjectDAO` need to read a `Doc` element, which again needs `ProjectDAO`, causing a circular dependency (therefore a StackOverflow):

```java
DocDAO.read(int id) --calls--> ProjectDAO.readAll(Doc d) --calls-> DocDAO.read(int id) --calls--> ProjectDAO.readAll(Doc d)...
```

`readAll` allows to recover all elements of type T given a filter
`create` allows to create an element of type T in database

how can I decouple these functionality without changing base classes (but just DAO)?
I would skip giving more code since it is very long.